# Как обновить Parent ViewModel данными которые изменились в PartialView ?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

На сайте MS написано в примечании следующее:

"частичное представление имеет доступ к данным родительского представления. В то же время, если оно обновляет данные, то эти обновления затронут только объект частичного представления ViewData.Данные родительского представления не изменяются."

[Метод RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial (HtmlHelper, String, ViewDataDictionary)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd470827(v=vs.108).aspx).

У меня Partial View изменяет данные Parent ViewModel (точнее добавляет в список который отображается с помощью PartialView новый элемент), а список в Parent ViewModel остается старым.

При обычном Post запросе все происходит на Ура. А вот когда приходится обновлять Partial View через ajax то Parent ViewModel не обновляет данные из измененного списка.

Думаю, что эта проблема не нова... но не могу найти подхода, пните в правильно направлении... спасибо заранее.

Технологии: Asp.net mvc 3, ajax.

Comment: неужели никто не сталкивался с подобным? или это настолько просто что даже объяснить лень?

Comment: @vpla: рискну предположить, всем лень читать простыню, которую вы назвали "коротким примером". Упростите вашу проблему до десятка строк, так чтобы _ни одной_ строки больше нельзя было выкинуть -- тогда ваш код станет читаемым. А пока, извините, всем влом.

Да, придётся поработать над действительно минимальным примером -- но тогда может быть вы и сами поймёте, в чём проблема?

Comment: упростил как смог, надеюсь понятно, если нет то задавайте вопросы обязательно отвечу.